# Mapping external to internal IP ranges

Tags: linux-networking, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, openvswitch

I have many namespaces on Kubernetes. Each namespace has it own IP range. For example n1 has 10.0.1.0/24 range, n2 has 10.0.2.0/24 and so on. Each pod in each namespace get ip base on the namespace ip range.
Also, I have external IP ranges as many IP ranges (namespaces) inside Kubernetes. For example I have 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.2.0/24 and so on.
Now I want to create a mapping between these external and internal IP ranges. For example I want to 192.168.1.100 map to 10.0.1.100. It's like having a vSwitch that has multiple ports.

I reviewed Open vSwitch and Ingress class. But I couldn't get a good result.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: To create a mapping between external and internal IP ranges in Kubernetes, you can use a combination of Network Address Translation (NAT) and Kubernetes Ingress, refer to this IBM doc on **[Mapping IP addresses using NAT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=rules-scenario-mapping-ip-addresses-using-nat)** and also check this medium Doc on **[kube-proxy and CNI](https://medium.com/@seifeddinerajhi/kube-proxy-and-cni-the-hidden-components-of-kubernetes-networking-eb30000bf87a)**,which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: It seems rather pointless when you can just route between private networks.